Can you have a nested list that's not a direct descendent of an li
The title explains it all.  I am curious if this is considered a nested list and if so is it valid HTML. I am also curious about any accessibility implications.  I tested with VoiceOver and it seems to read it as I would expect, but looking for any insight.
Let's say that I have an application that has a list of cards and for each card I have a list of badges.
example:
<ol>
  <li class="card">
     <div class="card-container">
        <h2>some title</h2>
        <ul class="badge-list">
          <li class="badge">some name</li>
          <li class="badge">another name</li>
          <li class="badge">another another name</li>
        </ul>
     </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
     <div class="card-container">
        <h2>some title</h2>
        <ul class="badge-list">
          <li class="badge">some name</li>
          <li class="badge">another name</li>
          <li class="badge">another another name</li>
        </ul>
     </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
     <div class="card-container">
        <h2>some title</h2>
        <ul class="badge-list">
          <li class="badge">some name</li>
          <li class="badge">another name</li>
          <li class="badge">another another name</li>
        </ul>
     </div>
  </li>
</ol>


"if this is considered a nested list". Considered by what? or whom? For what purpose? Is there specific normative accessibility text that mentions nested lists that you're asking about?

The simplest way to find out if it's valid HTML is to run it through the validator.

It's perfectly valid HTML code and screen readers correctly indicate the list and nested lists without any problem.
However, it's legitimate to ask yourself either the outer <ol> is really necessary, and if it wouldn't be too complicated semantics for nothing.
At least from my screen reader user point of view, this outer <ol> doesn't bring much usefulness, as there are already <h2> headings to clearly separate the different parts and allowing quick navigation.
Although you can put entire blocks in <li>, there are often better ways if items are longer or more complex than just a simple paragraph of text and/or simple elements such as links.
In your case, using <section> instead would make it simpler, and even clearer.

What if it's a chronologically ordered list of blog post cards? Would the <ol> provide helpful expectations about the quantity of posts listed, and the fact they have an implicit ordinality?

It wouldn't change my answer. With the code given, the item number isn't read when navigating by heading, and it anyway doesn't bring any really useful information (it's unnecessary to have it read). Blog posts are implicitly expected to be ordered by date. If you want to add numbering to your headings (for a more formal document), it ahs to be part of the element, so add them manually or use CSS counters.

I don't think all assistive tech users navigate exclusively by heading though, so it still seems worthwhile—even if it wouldn't be helpful to you.

Maybe not all, but navigation by heading is one of the most common method. But even when you simply use arrow keys, it says "One. Heading level two, some title", it's really not obvious to guess what this "one" is for. So it's probably also quite useless in that case, too.
